# Pulling specific information from C# WinForms error messages

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling, error-logging

I have a logging system set up in my C# WinForms project that writes to a log txt file. A typical error message looks like this:

```
Error : 
8:34:48 AM Tuesday, April 21, 2020
  :
  :System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at CrossReferenceTool.frmXRefTool.DefineControlsLayout() in <PathToSourceCsFile>:line 306
```

Is there any way to grab parts of that error message? Specifically, I'd like to pull the offending method (`DefineControlsLayout()` in this case) and the line number.

Comment: Is this a standard exception message as seen in the debugger?

Comment: @ChrisBD, I'm getting the error text from `catch (Exception ex)` and just sending `es.ToString()` to the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate a new StackTrace and go log the details from that after any exception occurs.

Original link I used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe?view=netframework-4.8

Example code
`using System.Diagnostics;`

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("Fail");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace(e, true);

    // Display the most recent function call.
    StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(0);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("  Exception in method: ");
    Console.WriteLine("      {0}", sf.GetMethod());

    if (st.FrameCount > 1)
    {
        // Display the highest-level function call 
        // in the trace.

        sf = st.GetFrame(st.FrameCount - 1);
        Console.WriteLine("  Original function call at top of call stack):");
        Console.WriteLine("      {0}", sf.GetMethod());

        // will only work if .pdb is included
        var lineNumber = sf.GetFileLineNumber();
        var fileName = sf.GetFileName();


    }
}
```

Comment: To retrieve the file info, you need to use the [constructor overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_StackTrace__ctor_System_Exception_System_Boolean_) `StackTrace st = new StackTrace(e, true).

Answer (score 1):

If you are already catching an Exception type then you have sub properties such as

`Exception.StackTrace
Exception.TargetSite`

I don't think that you can use them to pull the line of code though.